# SPFx: disabling console traces (by SPFx libraries)

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

Am a big fan of the console, and apply it [to the max](https://coderwall.com/p/fskzdw/colorful-console-log) (*and I hate it, IE does not do colors in the console*)

My console looks like this:

[image]

**Now the SPFx output is cluttering up my precious console, with info that is not for me:**

[image]

**I can filter it with:**

[image]

But that option is not sticky

#### Question:

- Can we disable the console trace from SPFx libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

noop it for now by adding this before any of the SPFx stuff gets loaded.

```
console.log(// extra wrapper so below code is taken out on minification
(function() {
    var noop = function noop() {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    window.log = {};

    methods.forEach(function (method) {
        if (Function.prototype.bind && (typeof console === 'object' || typeof console === 'function') && typeof console.log === 'object') {
            console[method] = this.call(console[method], console);
        }
        if (console[method]) {
            window.log[method] = console[method].bind(console);
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }, Function.prototype.bind);
  return "console is overriden"
})());
```

Then put it back the way it was or just use `log` instead.
As an aside, it really shouldn't have shipped this way.

Comment: I use the console myself to the max.. colors.. groupConsole.. the lot. If I noop I can't do my job. This Framework thing feels like pre-ordering a Tesla S3 and getting a lead-battery in advance

Comment: Using the idea above you'll be able to log. The code needs help though, since I wrote it on my phone. ;)

Comment: I've updated the code @Danny'365CSI'Engelman.

Comment: nice! One could work in their own log code, and still have it removed with Uglify I wrapped it in some extra JavaScript magic so this code is removed from minified versions as well

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible at this time.  Interesting idea though. Can you as it a feature request to the github issue list?

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/166